# How did Marvel train the cat Goose to cough up the Tesseract?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

In the ending credits of *Captain Marvel* Goose is hacking up what appears to be a hairball. How did the animal handlers make the cat convulse and hack the way she did? Was this all CGI?

[image: Goose]

*(See [high definition video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VR3Y58gbivk&vq=hd1080) here:)*

Comment: I´m not a cat expert, but my impression is that cats tend to convulse and spit hairballs on their own a lot and do not need any encouragement...

Comment: @Rebel-Scum A healthy cat that gets regular grooming (like, say, a movie star) is unlikely to ever develop hairballs.  Inducing a hairball type fit would be seen as animal cruelty, so we have to presume that some trickery was involved here.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Maybe a short hair would be unlikely to ever develop hairballs, but no level of grooming will prevent a long hair cat that self-grooms from developing hairballs.

Comment: I hope you're not referring specifically to the screenshot in your question, because the cat in that one is *obviously* CGI.

Comment: @ZeissIkon My cat would happily eat pine needles. Her gut would *not* happily digest them.

Comment: @VogonPoet No Bluray, I saw it at the cinema. Can you link to a bigger picture? It looks CGI to me -- the pose of the cat looks highly unnatural to me.

Comment: @VogonPoet you could add the blu Ray video. It’s available on YouTube now. This exact scene. Would make your question more clear for the ones in doubt.

Comment: @ZeissIkon - That is exactly what prompted the question. Barring doing something to make the cat gag, how did they humanely pull this off? Votes suggest it's unpopular to be concerned for animals.

Comment: @VogonPoet I don't think the downvotes are about the fact that you're showing concern for an animal.  It *might* be related to the idea that "how do movies do this thing" is a question better suited to Movies & TV than to sci-fi, especially when there are no specific science-fiction elements involved in answering that question (Tesseract aside, I expect they would accomplish this the same way they'd accomplish any scene of a cat hacking something up.)  Although I don't see any close votes, so maybe I'm off base there.

Comment: @Steve-O - I hope that's not correct, [Behind-the-scenes and fandom information](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is absolutely on-topic for this site. If my question were off-topic, there is a vote for this as well.

Comment: The downvotes will be from people who believe the question is low-effort because the cat is "obviously" CGI. It's not because animal welfare is "unpopular" here, and it's *certainly* not because the question is off-topic. Personally, I think it's admirable that Marvel's CGI has gotten so good that you believed it was a real cat and got concerned enough to ask this.

Comment: It's "obvious" on the VHS version perhaps. Certainly not to anyone who watched the film as intended. Energy blasts from CM's hands are "obvious." a young Coulson was not. Etc.

Answer (score 15):

## It could have very well been CGI

---

As mentioned by the VFX technician involved in Captain Marvel, Chris Townsend in his interview with the [Huffington Post](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/its-time-to-talk-about-a-captain-marvel-cut-scene-and-other-secrets-from-the-movie_n_5c9422c3e4b057f73308d847?guccounter=1):

> **There are about over 100 shots of the cat in the film, 70 or 80 of them are CG**. So convincing was the CGI that, [according to Townsend], even the movie's directors Anna Boden and Ryan Fleck couldn't tell the computer-generated cat from the real ones.

**So, about 80% CG shots for the cat**. This could very well include the tesseract scene.

Additionally, Townsend mentions that,

> "Whenever Brie’s holding a cat, almost always it’s a CG cat, and a lot of the times when the cat is on Nick Fury’s lap or is wandering around, it’s CG as well.

Because Brie Larson is allergic to cats, and S.L. Jackson is not so fond of cats either.

> "There’s a lot of stuff that I would look at as a viewer and think, ‘Well, surely they could’ve got a cat to do that.’ In reality, no, we couldn’t get the cat to perform correctly in the same takes we got the actors to perform"

Well, cats do *convulse and spit hairballs* quite frequently, it is not feasible to have a camera ready all the time simply to shoot a cat throwing up (MCU isn't that patient).

**PS**: Just a reminder; They actually CGI'd the gun in S.L.Jackson's hand in *Spider-Man: Far From Home* (see [this tweet](https://twitter.com/mcu_direct/status/1150455139620274177)). This tells you how much the MCU uses CGI.

Comment: After what that one did to his eye, it’s no wonder SLJ doesn’t like cats!

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill  or maybe it’s the other way around 

Comment: This still seems speculative, though it is helpful to guide further research.

Comment: @VogonPoet when no exact answer with a trustable source (other than wiki pages) is available, speculations are acceptable as answers. As Sherlock says- *when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth*